# Convert Currency

Tags: java, android, currency

I have got an App where it's needed to convert a set amount of money at runtime, as the App will be deployed in different countries.

Let's say I have a set price at 100$. Is there a simple way to convert it to another currency (that I get based on the Locale of the device)?

Cheers

Comment: You realize that currency rates fluctuate, right? There's nothing built into Java to handle that.

Comment: You can use google api: [link](https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=USD&to=INR) Or European central bank api: [link](http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml) for updated currency value

Answer (score -1):

I am using google finance calculator as user interact with your app you can fetch converted data by using it in php.

```
function convertCurrency($amount, $from, $to){
$url  = "https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from&to=$to";
$data = file_get_contents($url);
preg_match("/<span class=bld>(.*)<\/span>/",$data, $converted);
$converted = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "", $converted[1]);
return round($converted, 3);
}
```

I'm using USD to INR converter.
    call this function

```
echo convertCurrency(1, "USD", "INR");
```

Answer (score -1):

you can't do that by java code cause currency rates flatuating every time.. you can use this api it will updated automatically when currency rates change---

```
<?php
$from = $_POST["from"];
$to = $_POST["to"];
$amount = $_POST["amount"];
$rawData = currencyConvert($from,$to,$amount);
$regex  = '#\<span class=bld\>(.+?)\<\/span\>#s';
preg_match($regex, $rawData, $converted);
$result = $converted[0];
preg_match('!\d+(?:\.\d+)?!', $result, $result);
echo $result[0];

function currencyConvert($from,$to,$amount){
     $url = "http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from&to=$to"; 
     $request = curl_init(); 
     $timeOut = 0; 
     curl_setopt ($request, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
     curl_setopt ($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
     curl_setopt ($request, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)"); 
     curl_setopt ($request, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeOut); 
     $response = curl_exec($request); 
     curl_close($request); 
     return $response;
  } 

?>
```

Comment: OP asked for a Java solution and you are telling him he cant do it in Java. It is possible to recreate that PHP script in Java..

Comment: @LaurensMäkel I gave a api which can be easily integrate with java

Comment: Why try to integrate an PHP API with an Java application if you can solve the problem in pure Java..